# The port name is illegal or couldn't be connected to the device

Tags: c#, printing, epson, opos

I'm getting the mentioned error when trying to claim the Epson TM-T88V ticket printer.
I have installed:

OPOS ADK for .NET
POS for .NET v1.12

I was printing fine from my latop for many days and from another computer, both working fine. I then decided to take both machines where the printer will be working. And from then on I get the above error.

Hope for somebody to shine some light, would be very helpfull.
Thanks

Update:
After executing the health check utillity I get this error:
================== Exception =====================
Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException
ErrorCode : Illegal (106)
ErrorCodeExtended : 0
Message : PortHandler Win32 error.
Target : Void Claim(Int32)

### StackTrace

at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_11_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.Claim(Int32 iTimeout)
   at CheckHealthTest.MainForm.ExecuteCheckHealth(DeviceInfo objInfo)
   at CheckHealthTest.MainForm.btnCheckHealth_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
---------InnerException-----------
jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.CommControlException
Message : PortHandler Win32 error.
Target : Void ThrowCommException(Int32, System.String)

### StackTrace

at jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.CommonPortIO.ThrowCommException(Int32 iError, String strMessage)
   at jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.PortHandlerIO.ThrowJNIErrorException(Int32 JNIErrorID)
   at jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.PortHandlerIO.PortOpen()
   at jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.PortControl.OpenPort()
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_11_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.OpenPort()

***After, uninstalling the Epson Advanced drivers and running a health check I get the following exception:***

ErrorCodeExtended : 1001
Message : The port name is illegal, or couldn't be connected to the device.
Target : Void Claim(Int32)

### StackTrace

en jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_11_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.Claim(Int32 iTimeout)
   en CheckHealthTest.MainForm.ExecuteCheckHealth(DeviceInfo objInfo)
   en CheckHealthTest.MainForm.btnCheckHealth_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
---------InnerException-----------
jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.CommControlException
Message : The port name is illegal.
Target : Void ThrowCommException(Int32, System.String)

### StackTrace

en jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.CommonPortIO.ThrowCommException(Int32 iError, String strMessage)
   en jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.CommonPortIO.ThrowCommException(Int32 iError)
   en jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.PortHandlerIO.PortOpen()
   en jp.co.epson.pos.comm.v2_0001.PortControl.OpenPort()
   en jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_11_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.OpenPort()

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any Code to accompany this issue that you are faced with..?

Comment: We will be unable to help you unless you ask a specfic question.  This site is geared towards programming questions so you need to be very specfic.

Comment: No I dont get any error codes

Comment: Do you use the the Epson OPOS driver installed and NOT the "Epson Advanced Printer Driver"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the printer test using the Epson Check Health Utility is reporting errors (like you've previously mentioned), this is not a fault of EPOS-Excel.  This simply means that the Epson OPOS driver is not configured correctly for your printer.  Once the Check Health Utility reports an "ok" test result, EPOS-Excel should have no problem using the printer.

Do you use the the Epson OPOS driver installed and NOT the "Epson Advanced Printer Driver"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I installed the Epson advanced printer driver , OPOS ADK for .NET and then POS for .NET v1.12.

Comment: I've updated my question with the exception I received after running a health check.

Comment: You only need the OPOS driver installed and in some cases, the Windows driver can casue conflict issues.  Assuming everything else is correct, what happens when you perform a "Check Health Interactive" test on the printer using the Epson Check Health utility?

Comment: Hi, I uninstalled the Epson advanced driver. I updated my question with the exception I received after running the health check. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Let's ensure that only the OPOS driver is installed  -- this way you don't have multiple drivers fighting for control of the printer port.

Comment: I uninstalled the "EPson advanced driver", restarted my machine, then, uninstalled "OPOS ADK for .NET", restarted and installed "OPOS ADK for .NET" again. I then ran SetupPos.exe, selected the PosPrinter and chose "usb" port, then ran the health check. (To be honest I really do not have any experience with these printers. I managed to get it running a few days ago, developed my printing tickets and out of the bloom I recevied the Port invalid error I mention), anyway thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: Ok, what OS are you running Win7 64bit?

Comment: Remove All printer drivers:)  Download latest EPSON OPOS ADK for .NET https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=2905&scat=39&pcat=3

 
1) Install POS.net 
2) Install EPSON OPOS
3) run TM USB
4) run setupPos

Comment: Is TM USB a seperate download?

Comment: Really gratefull for the help but still getting the : The port name is illegal, or couldn't be connected to the device

Comment: can you look on back to see model for sure?

Comment: Sticker on the side says: EPSON TM-T88V, MODEL: M244A

Comment: Just updated my question with another "screen print" of how the printer appears to windows 7. Status : Printer not available.

Comment: Stupid verification---check the USB cord to make sure it is connected properly.. what does your device manager look like

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I managed to get it working and your not going to believe what the reason was. I spent a few days with the printer working fine, moved to some other place and it stopped working, well after hours trying to get it working again, I decided to change the usb cable, and it started working again. Unbelievable. Thanks a lot for your help and time, much appreciated.

Comment: I never like those type of errors :)  Hope the posts will help someone else though :)

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the Driver conflict.  It appears I had the same issue with Java JPOS conflicting with the APD driver.  I uninstalled the APD tool suite and the printer driver worked again.  Seems Epson has some issue with their drivers.  I would think that windows print drivers shouldn't conflict with their own driver software.